# I get "integrity constraint violated - child record found" in console

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle10g, illegalargumentexception

when I tried to delete the parent table. But, I want to turn it as a message so that it does'nt allow me to delete the table. How can I convert that exception into message?(IN SPRING BOOT)

Comment: by implementing Exception handling, I would assume.

Comment: Yes. I have used exception handling and it can be seen in postman. But, I am still getting that error in the console.

Comment: only if you yourself print it, or haven't done good exception handling